# Word Wrap in Table Cell in BOOKTABS Tables

Tags: tables, booktabs, wordbreak

### In a Nutshell:

How can you provide word wrap in left-aligned table cell when you are using the package `bookstabs`?

### My Problem in Detail:

I am writing a scientific paper to be (hopefully) published in an ACM magazine. The document class includes the package `booktabs`: https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs and the style guide does not allow to use other table styles.

Before that, in a draft document, I had this table, using the package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray} % <-- line 2
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tblr}{X[l]X[l]rrr} % <-- line 5
        \hline
        Authors/Editors & Title & Pages & Year & Ref. \\
        \hline
        David Salomon and Giovanni Motta & 
        Handbook of Data Compression & 1,370 & 2010 & [1] \\
        Colt McAnlis and Aleks Haecky & 
        Understanding Compression: Data Compression 
        for Modern Developers & 241 & 2016 & [2] \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr} % <-- line 15
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It produces this table:

[image: table made with package tabularray]
<sup>fig 1: table made with package `tabularray`</sup>

Then I tried it in the ACM template that uses `booktabs` and I failed. Here is an example code using this package. Only lines 2, 5 and 15 are different (marked with comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- line 2
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{llrrr} % <-- line 5
        \hline
        Authors/Editors & Title & Pages & Year & Ref. \\
        \hline
        David Salomon and Giovanni Motta & 
        Handbook of Data Compression & 1,370 & 2010 & [1] \\
        Colt McAnlis and Aleks Haecky & 
        Understanding Compression: Data Compression 
        for Modern Developers & 241 & 2016 & [2] \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} % <-- line 15
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: table made with package booktabs]
<sup>fig 2: table made with package `booktabs` and `llrrr`</sup>

There is no word wrap and the table is too wide to fit on the page. It is cut off at the right side.

With `tabularray` I can specify word wrap in a left-aligned table cell with the parameter `X[l]` (in line 5). When I try this with `booktabs` I get an error message ("LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg") and table cells without word wrap and centered text:

[image: second version using booktabs]
<sup>fig 3: table made with package `booktabs` and `X[l]X[l]rrr`</sup>

When I replace `X[l]` with `l` I get what you can see in figure 2 (without an error).

On https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs is a documentation of the package `booktabs` which is 18 pages long, but it nowhere mentions column widths, word wrap or similar topics. In fact all 18 pages deal only with one topic: the thickness of horizontal lines, which is not very helpful.

### Here is my question:

Please can you tell me, what I must do to create a table with word wraps as shown in my first example, but for the package `bookstabs`?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with booktabs: you used no paragraph-like column specifiers. Unrelated: with booktabs, you should not use `\hline` but one of `\toprule, \bottomrule`or `\midrule` in order to have some vertical padding.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, you are right. I used `\toprule` etc. but I found out that this had no influence on my problem and I wanted to keep my examples as simple as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with you using `booktabs` but that you have not specified how you want the columns to be set. Use `p{width}` for a column with multiple text lines.

```
% booktabsprob.tex  SE 640799

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- line 2
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%    \begin{tabular}{llrrr} % <-- line 5
    \begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}rrr} % <-- line 5
        \hline
        Authors/Editors & Title & Pages & Year & Ref. \\
        \hline
        David Salomon and Giovanni Motta & 
        Handbook of Data Compression & 1,370 & 2010 & [1] \\
        Colt McAnlis and Aleks Haecky & 
        Understanding Compression: Data Compression 
        for Modern Developers & 241 & 2016 & [2] \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} % <-- line 15
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `tabularray` and its library `booktabs` (which load `booktabs` package too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tblr}{colsep = 4pt,
                 colspec = {@{} X[0.8,l]X[1.2,l]rrr @{}}
                 }
    \toprule
Authors/Editors & Title & Pages & Year & Ref.   \\
    \midrule
David Salomon and Giovanni Motta 
                & Handbook of Data Compression 
                        & 1,370 & 2010 & [1]    \\
Colt McAnlis and Aleks Haecky 
                & Understanding Compression: Data Compression
        for Modern Developers 
                        &   241 & 2016 & [2]    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution, using `tabularx`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{booktabs} % <-- line 2

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXrrr} % <-- line 5
            \toprule
            Authors/Editors & Title & Pages & Year & Ref. \\
            \midrule
            David Salomon and Giovanni Motta &
            Handbook of Data Compression & 1,370 & 2010 & [1] \\ \addlinespace
            Colt McAnlis and Aleks Haecky &
            Understanding Compression: Data Compression
            for Modern Developers & 241 & 2016 & [2] \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx} % <-- line 15
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You asked,

> How can you provide [line wrapping] in left-aligned table cell when you are using the package `booktabs`?

Enabling automatic line wrapping is completely distinct from any features provided by the `booktabs` package. As you've discovered, the `l` column type does not provide automatic line breaking. I suggest you load the `tabularx` package, use its eponymous `tabularx` environment instead of `tabular`, set the overall width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`, and employ the package's `X` column type for the first two columns.

Relative to the `tabularx`-based approach pursued by @Bernard in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640806/5001), the approach pursued below (a) gets rid of the whitespace padding at the left- and right hand edges of the table, (b) doesn't fully justify the cell contents in columns 1 and 2, (c) center-sets rather than right-aligns the contents of columns 3 thru 5, and (d) employs the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package to align the numbers in column 3 on their (implicit) decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for S column type
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
          LL 
          S[table-format=4.0,group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]
          cc @{}} 
        \toprule
        Authors/Editors & Title & {Pages} & Year & Ref. \\
        \midrule
        David Salomon and Giovanni Motta & 
        Handbook of Data Compression & 1370 & 2010 & [1] \\
        \addlinespace
        Colt McAnlis and Aleks Haecky & 
        Understanding Compression: Data Compression 
        for Modern Developers & 241 & 2016 & [2] \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```